# Plotting a Chart with different amount of data in C#

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to plot a line chart but I have problems to figure how can I plot a chart with different amount of data in C#.

Example:
Let's say you have a .csv file with two columns and ten rows. The first column always had data (i.e. datetime), but the second column had data in only four rows (the other six rows the data is zero).
How can I plot this chart without having this kind of graphs? I want to have a continuous chart and with the same interval but with the points attached with each other.

Thanks!

Here is an image of the graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFcE4.png

My code:

```
public MainForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     setupChart();
}

private void cmdLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //I read the .csv file with a try/catch using a streamReader and save the data in
     //a class named Measurement that has two variables: _time and _measure.
     //The Measurement created is add to a List of Measurements.

     //I pass the List of Measurements as a DataSource to the DataGrid
     grdMeasurements.DataSource = _measurementList;

     //I pass the List of Measurements as a DataSource to the Chart.
     chartLineMatching.DataSource = _measurementList;
     chartLineMatching.DataBind();
}

public void setupChart()
{       
      chartLineMatching.Series.Clear();
      chartLineMatching.Titles.Clear();

      Series dataSerie = new Series("Series1", 200);
      dataSerie.XValueMember = "Time";
      dataSerie.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM HH:mm";
      dataSerie.YValueMembers = "Value5";
      dataSerie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0;0}" + "°";
      dataSerie.BorderWidth = 2;
      dataSerie.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
      chartLineMatching.Series.Add(dataSerie);
      chartLineMatching.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;

      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Interval = 4;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Format = "{0;0}" + "%";

      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;
      chartLineMatching.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Filter out the zero-value from the datasource and make the xaixs indexed: chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to just skip over the data points that have "0" in the value column.  How to do this all depends on the code you are using to create the chart from the csv data.  Without showing any code, we can't really help you.

But basically you would need to pass your data through a filter which would remove the points you want to skip, and then create the graph from the filtered dataset.

Comment: I did that, but the graph is shorter because of the intervals (it's different if I have 30 entries between rows with data and non data than 6 with data.

Comment: I would check to see if there was a way to configure the graph so that it can be formatted the way you want, regardless of the input data.  It's not a great idea to have the layout of the graph be based on the data points.